# Plücker coordinates and grassmannians

Tags: algebraic-geometry, grassmannian

Let $X$ denote the set of lines in $\mathbb{P}_k^3$ and $\varphi:X\rightarrow\mathbb{P}_k^5$ be the morphism that sends, once we have chosen a reference, each $(a_0:\cdots:a_3)\vee(b_0:\cdots:b_3)$ to 
$$(\Delta_{01}:\Delta_{02}:\Delta_{03}:\Delta_{12}:\Delta_{13}:\Delta_{23}),$$
where each $\Delta_{ij}$ is given by the determinant
$$
\Delta_{ij}=\left|\begin{array}{cc}
a_i & a_j \\
b_i & b_j\end{array}\right|
$$
Which is the relationship between the Plücker coordinates of a line and the intersections of such line with the reference tetrahedron? I am aware that in many textbooks the approach to this problem is exterior algebras. Is there an elementary, alternative way of seeing that relationship? On the other hand, would that relationship imply that $\varphi$ is injective? If so, how?

Comment: Just a gentle query: why would you want to do Projective Geometry without using Exterior Algebras? Sometimes one has to grit one's teeth and learn the language ..otherwise we're condemned to live in the past.

Comment: I agree with you that we have to learn new tools in order to solve new, harder problems, but I also find it interesting to see if there can be an elementary approach to problems. In this case, both Plücker and Grassmann's contributions date back to the mid XIX century... I don't think they came up with the notion of exterior algebra without a motivating example.

Comment: Yes, I agree up to a point: one should not use sledgehammers to crack nuts. But it's a long time since 1850, and I can't really believe that a serious projective geometer has not got the theory of exterior algebras mastered--otherwise it's all flashes of genius and ad hoc manipulations of determinants and their minors.

Comment: Compared to the Plücker coordinates on the Grassmannian, exterior algebras *are* elementary. I didn't think you could get away with getting a PhD in math without learning about exterior algebras. It's really not even that hard a concept.

Comment: I am in my last year of my mathematics degree, I know all I need to know about exterior algebras... I just want to use the tools that I have used during this course, in which nobody has mentioned exterior algebras.

Comment: Actually, your education level mustn't be very advanced if, first, you consider that a question like this (I haven't even started my MSc yet) can be related to having or not a PhD and secondly you (both) prefer to waste time commenting about how easy this stuff is rather than focusing on what mathstackexchange really is about: sharing knowledge.

Comment: I started studying this stuff in my junior year of college as well. It doesn't make it college level.